# AzureML webservice deployment with custom Environment - /var/runit does not exist

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I'm struggling to deploy a model with a custom environment through the azureml SDK.

I have built a docker image locally and pushed it to azure container registry to use it for environment instantiating. This is how my dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi3.1.2-ubuntu18.04
FROM python:3.9.12
        
# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
        
# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
        
# Install requirement for deploying the service
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y runit
        
# Install pip requirements
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install azureml-defaults
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I want to deploy the webservice locally for testing, so I am following the steps according to official documentation:

```
ws = Workspace(
    subscription_id='mysub_id', 
    resource_group='myresource_group', 
    workspace_name='myworkspace'
)
        
model = Model.register(
    ws, 
    model_name='mymodel', 
    model_path='./Azure_Deployment/mymodel_path'
)
        
container = ContainerRegistry()
container.address = 'myaddress'
myenv = Environment.from_docker_image('myenv_name', 'img/img_name:v1', container)
        
inference_config = InferenceConfig(
    environment=myenv, 
    source_directory='./Azure_Deployment', 
    entry_script='echo_score.py',
)
        
deployment_config = LocalWebservice.deploy_configuration(port=6789)
        
service = Model.deploy(
    ws, 
    "myservice", 
    [model], 
    inference_config, 
    deployment_config, 
    overwrite=True,
)
service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
```

This is what I get from the logs:

[service container logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLafe.png)

Checking into the resulting container for the service I can see indeed there is no /runit folder inside /var. There is also no other folders created for the service besides the azureml-app containing my model's files.

I would really appreciate any insights to what's going on here as I have no clue at this point.

Answer (score -1):

The error says, it's init() failure and once check whether your model in your workspace is using `register()` function or not on the model object. If not mentioned, then it will be a model path failure.

```
def init():
    global model
    model_path = Model.get_model_path('Modelpath')
    model = joblib.load(model_path)
```

Check the model registry section in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-deploy-and-where#registermodel

Answer (score -1):

1. With “docker ps -a”, the image created by AML SDK had a command of “runsvdir /var/runit”
   a.  Article here confirms  https://github.com/liupeirong/liupeirong.github.io/tree/master/amlDockerImage
   2.Try extracting directory structure from the docker image using undocker project https://github.com/larsks/undocker/
2. After extracting directory structure of the docker image, find program “runsvdir” and also directory “/var/runit”

Here is sample for custom docker image for “Tensorflow Object Detection” model and deploy same by following this documentation page - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-deploy-custom-docker-image#use-a-custom-base-image

you can use an existing ACR during workspace creation. Check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-manage-workspace-cli?tabs=vnetpleconfigurationsv1cli%2Ccreatenewresources%2Cworkspaceupdatev1%2Cworkspacesynckeysv1%2Cworkspacedeletev1#use-existing-resources) for details.